# Is it possible to crack SHA256, when you know the answer is a coordinate?

Tags: python, coordinates, sha256, cracking

I need to crack a sha256 hash, and I know the answer is in coordinates, but I don't know what are the coordinate values
example:

```
3f1c756daec9ebced7ff403acb10430659c13b328c676c4510773dc315784e4e
58.375782 26.742632
```

Is it possible to create a python script that makes two variables (both with the value 00.000000), then add them togheter (ex: `k=i+" "+j`), then converts k into sha256 and compares it to the sha256, I'm trying to crack. If it doesn't equal the sha256 being cracked, then it adds `i` a value (`i=i+00.000001`) and triess again. and so on and so on

Comment: Sure, you can bruteforce the hash. With time.. You only need to try 10**16 combinations.

Comment: You definitely could have written Martijn's answer yourself, you described the algorithm in your question.

Comment: That coordinate string won't produce that specific hash digest. What is the *exact* format of the input string for the coordinates? In My answer I am assuming the hash function is fed a `xx.xxxxxx yy.yyyyyy` coordinate; e.g. a number formatted to 2.6 digits with 0 padding, and a space between the two coordinates.

Comment: If you're looking for ways to attack SHA256 that are better than brute force… there are known preimaging attacks for creating collisions, but no published attacks (as of 2014) for reversing a hash. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Cryptanalysis_and_validation) describes them at a layman level. If you want to actually take advantage of them, you will need to learn more details. If someone has found a new attack recently, the chance that they will post it as an answer to your question rather than in the various public crypto forums seems pretty slim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Producing all possible coordinates between `00.000000` and `99.999999` is easy enough:

```
from itertools import product
import hashlib

digits = '0123456789'

for combo in product(digits, repeat=16):
    coords = '{}.{} {}.{}'.format(
        ''.join(combo[:2]), ''.join(combo[2:8]),
        ''.join(combo[8:10]), ''.join(combo[10:]))
    hash = hashlib.sha256(coords).hexdigest()
    if hash == '3f1c756daec9ebced7ff403acb10430659c13b328c676c4510773dc315784e4e':
        print coords
        break
```

This'll brute-force all 10**16 (a big number) combinations. Sit back and relax, this'll take a while.

And by 'a while', we really mean *not in your lifetime, or anyone else's*. Just iterating over all possible combinations produced by `product()` takes a huge amount of time, as each added digit to try increases the time required by a factor of 10:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> digits = '0123456789'
>>> timeit(lambda: deque(product(digits, repeat=8), 0), number=5)
3.014396679995116
>>> timeit(lambda: deque(product(digits, repeat=9), 0), number=5)
30.99540744899423
```

If producing all possible combinations of 8 digits takes .8 seconds (4s divided by 5 repetitions), 9 digits takes 8 seconds, you can extrapolate from that that 10 digits takes almost 1.5 minutes, etc. Just producing all possible combinations of 16 digits takes 1 million (10 ** 6) times as much time as 10 digits, so 963 days or just onder 3 *years* to run those in a loop. You could split this task up across 2000 different processes on a large number of computers with enough cores in total to run those processes in parallel, to reduce that to under 12 hours.

Then the loop body itself takes about 2.4 seconds per million iterations:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> combo = tuple(choice(digits) for _ in range(16))  # random combination for testing
>>> timeit("""\
... coords = '{}.{} {}.{}'.format(
...     ''.join(combo[:2]), ''.join(combo[2:8]),
...     ''.join(combo[8:10]), ''.join(combo[10:]))
... hash = hashlib.sha256(coords).hexdigest()
... if hash == '3f1c756daec9ebced7ff403acb10430659c13b328c676c4510773dc315784e4e': pass
... """, 'from __main__ import combo; import hashlib')
2.3429908752441406
```

But you have 10 ** 10 (10 thousand million) more times work than that, totaling roughly 743 **years** of computation work. Even being able to run 20 thousand parallel processes won't reduce that to a reasonable number (that's still about 13.5 years of work).

Python is just not fast enough for this task. Using GPUs it should be possible to reach [500 million hashes per second (0.5 Gigahash / s)](https://www.tweaktown.com/articles/8229/ethereum-mining-1gh-40-gpus-5000-per-month/index.html), at which point you could run the above brute-force operation and find a solution in about 230 days on such a system. At a cost, of course, because such a rig would cost about $3000-$4000 a month to run! But with enough dedicated hardware you can certainly 'crack' the hash in 'humane' timeline.

Comment: Though "a while" is much better than "longer than the time left until the heat death of the universe". My guesstimate is something in the order of a few years (at best three months), assuming no parallelization.

Comment: Maybe you could only count the coordinates of the land area on earth to eliminate the unnecessary computation.

Comment: They seem to be global positionning coordinates though, so the ranges are probably [-180..+180], [-90..+90]

Comment: This assumes there is no Salt (cryptography)

Answer (score 2):

One of the common claims about hashes is that they discard information, therefore they cannot be reversed. There's infinite messages that have the same hash. You can't know which of the infinite messages that give the same hash is correct.

Of course in practice, a brute force attack often works - either because your search strategy is likely to find the real original message first (most messages with hash collisions are obviously wrong in some trivial way - e.g. the wrong format - and won't turn up in the search because of that) or because your attack needs a different message with the same hash anyway.

In your case, what you know about the message means there's less information in the message than (apparently) in the hash. Of course hashing doesn't create new information, so that means many hashes cannot occur for any co-ordinate strings. You have (with very high probability for good hash algorithms) a 1:1 relationship between possible hashes and possible messages. In principle, you have an encrypted form of your message which can be decrypted.

Many people would call me an idiot for saying this, of course. After all, you still have to find all the hashes for all the possible messages. That may be faster than some people think, but it's a long way from trivial.

It has already been pointed out that there are 10^16 possible combinations based on your co-ordinate format. One thing to check is whether all values for all those digits are possible (and equally probable). Using floating point arithmetic internally shouldn't be a problem - double precision floats aren't 8-digit decimals, but 53 bits of mantissa should be plenty to ensure all those decimal digits are fully in use. However, it may be worth checking that there's no other limitation that reduces the number of cases to check - the obvious one being the precision in how those co-ordinates are measured.

Even if certain digit values are less probable than others, that means ordering the search to check more likely values first will save a lot of time for crackers.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are not always set to a fixed number of decimal digits, but instead truncate the unneeded extra zeros for each value as most systems do by default, the actual number of permutations for a pair of numbers with the range of values 00.000001 to 99.999999 is significantly larger than 10^16, the correct value is:

6.829256694940521983972864462526391299880147836552973594 × 10^11131417

Yes that is 10 to the 11,131,417th power, cracking it would be impossible by any stretch of the imagination.  This is because the value "10.010000" could be represented as "10.010","10.0100", and so on.

There are various optimizations you can make to speed up your cracking routine, but considering the size of the number set you are attacking any optimization is not likely to reduce the computation time to within a human lifespan.

Your only optimization that is reliable with sha256 is to use a pre-hash of one of the coordinate values and clone that to iteratively hash the other coordinate point.  So if you knew what one of the latitude values was, you could generate a pre-hash with that and then feed it the longitude value in a loop, avoiding some overhead.

So,

```
res = hashlib.sha256("xyz")
res.hexdigest()
```

is equal to:

```
res = hashlib.sha256("x").update("yz")
res.hexdigest()
```

which is equal to:

```
res = hashlib.sha256("x")
res.update("y")
res.update("z")
res.hexdigest()
```

Using that property you can remove overhead from your script by cloning part of the calculation instead of creating it new, like:

```
prehash = hashlib.sha256("x")

while(looping):
    res = prehash.clone()
    res.update("yz")
    compare = (res.hexdigest() == hashlib.sha256("xyz"))
    # ( compare equals true in the line above )
```

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning for the first paragraph? There exists a bijection between the set of zero-padded strings and the set of strings with the extra zeros trimmed off, so the number of candidate strings is exactly the same, no?

Comment: If your line of think was along the lines of "there exist more strings of length up to 16 than strings of length exactly 16", then that assumption doesn't actually change the number of candidate strings all that much. Consider this upper bound: pretend that the coordinates are completely arbitrary strings of length up to 16 taken from the alphabet `[0-9 .]`. Regardless of the zero-padding behavior you pick, any coordinate string will be contained in that collection, right? But it only contains less than `10^18` elements (calculate it yourself: `log10(sum(12**i for i in range(17)))`).

Comment: @Brian61354270 Because sha256() takes in a stream of bytes it will treat each zero that is encoded as an additional byte to read in, and even if the bytes are all zeros each additional zero read in will still turn the hash output into a new random string.

I am also assuming that the long and lat values can have different length of digits, like ( 20.05, 31.005 ).  That will be an entirely unique set compared to ( 20.050, 31.005 ) for example, so we have combinations of combinations.

Comment: I worded this last sentence funny last time, what I mean to say is that each set is a permutation of length as well as value, so each pair of values could produce new hashes based on any zeros padding added, as well as the placement and/or presence of a period or comma in the value.

Comment: You're correct that there are more possible stings when we allow the coordinates to be variable length (with different zero-paddings), but your counting approach is still off. You're somehow counting the subset of strings that represent valid coordinates to be much larger than the _containing_ set of _arbitrary_ strings of _any_ length from the same alphabet. I think you'll agree that that's just not possible. If you share your counting approach, someone might be able to point out where it's overcounting.

Comment: If it helps, I find it suspect how you're referring to permutations and combinations here, since neither concept seems to apply. It may be that in your counting you're considering certain digits to have "identity" when they really ought not, e.g. implicitly treating two "9"s being distinguishable

Comment: In my post I made an error and considered free permutations per combination which is why my number was so high, here is what I would answer which should be more accurate.

If we assume a fixed width decimal for latitude and longitude are used, and use 6 digits of precision to the right of the decimal like his example, and include the negative latitude and longitude values as well since they are used for coordinates, then I show that there would be 64,800,000,000,000,000 or 64.8 quadrillion potential combinations ( 6.48×10¹⁶ ).  

continued...

Comment: If the system truncates trailing zero digits from the latitude and longitude as might be likely, for example Google Maps does this, then we have a permutation of the length also because each coordinate can be between 1 to 8 digits long for the longitude and 1 and 9 digits for the latitude.

So if I take the permutations on length which give us 36 times the original set size ( the mean of 8 and 9's product ) then the total combinations would come to:

2,332,800,000,000,000,000 or 2.3328 quintillion combinations ( 2.3328×10¹⁸ ).